# Is it possible to use Vim's power (Vim buffers...) while doing 3 way merge in Meld?

Tags: vimdiff, merge

Is it possible to use `Vim's power` (Vim buffers...) while doing 3 way merge in `Meld` ?

I can see in Meld you can change the default editor:

`edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> default editor`

I tried to change that to vim

However, I can not use Vim's power in the meld. Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably set it to gvim. Alternately, use vim as the mergetool and bypass meld completely

Comment: ok will give gvim a try, also I pretty much like meld because of its own advantages, so I don't wanna move away from it.